# Rust crate custom build command fails at CMake Deprication Warning

Tags: rust, cmake

While compiling the crate expat-sys v2.1.6, the custom build command failed with status 101 and the following under `--- stderr`:

```
  CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:6 (cmake_minimum_required):
    Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
    CMake.

    Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
    CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
```

The following was the configuration it printed:

```
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CMAKE_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CMAKE = None
  CMAKE = None
```

my current cmake version is 3.25.1, my rustc version is 1.66.0 and my OS is Fedora 37

cmake was installed recently without any configuration

While I was trying to learn how to use WGPU using [this tutorial](https://sotrh.github.io/learn-wgpu/), the build failed while compiling dependencies. I'm unfamiliar with CMake so I don't know how to read it's errors very well.

Comment: Possibly related: https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-fix-cmake-minimum-required-deprecation-warning/2487

Answer (score -1):

After further digging (asking ChatGPT for help), I tried installing expat-devel and it compiled.